# Making a query acording to first 3 letter of database value

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

I can get sum value of my "ctr" from my database with below query. But my ctr is longer than 5 letter. I must check the first 3 letter and get sum value acording to this 3 letter

```
String qry15 = "SELECT SUM(sales),SUM(box) FROM table WHERE ctr = '"+ comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'" ;
```

So I need something like  FROM table WHERE ctr.first3letter

How is it possible to do it?

Comment: You should not concatenate values into a query string like that. It is unsafe as it opens you to SQL injection. You should be using a prepared statement with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substr()` from MySql:

```
String qry15 = "SELECT SUM(sales),SUM(box) FROM table WHERE substr(ctr,1,3) = '"+ comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'";
```

`substr()` works similar to the Java `String.substring()`. Only the indicies are counted differently (starting with 1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT` also,

```
String qry15 = "SELECT SUM(sales),SUM(box) FROM table WHERE LEFT(ctr,3) = '"+ comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'";
```

`LEFT()` returns a specified number of characters from the left of the string.